# jQuery change the SRC and ID of an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, src

On my blog, I'm using a script that reveals anonymous messages as their normal username instead of anonymous. The script works fine on pages that I can make, but on pages that are default generated by my host (such as /ask, containing a message box which I cannot edit), I can't edit the code for the ask box so therefore it won't work. If anyone could provide a jQuery code that will

1. Change the iFrame SRC with an ID of #askbox from "http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/jamescharless.com" to "http://jamescharless.com/askbox"
2. Remove the ID from the iFrame so it simply doesn't have an id

If anyone could help me it would be EXTREMELY helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This should change your IFrame src

```
$("#askbox").attr("src", "http://jamescharless.com/askbox");
```

You could try:

```
$("#askbox").removeAttr("id");
```

Combine the two:

```
$("#askbox").attr("src", "http://jamescharless.com/askbox").removeAttr("id");
```

Trying to solve your scripting problem...

Opening the page in a debugger you can run:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper');
```

but not

```
document.getElementById('ask_form') - it throws an error
```

**Plan B**

How about injecting a fresh IFrame?

```
$('#ask_form').parent().html('<iframe width="100%" height="149" 
    src="http://jamescharless.com/askbox" frameBorder="0" 
    scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent;">
    </iframe>');
```

Comment: It's a permissions issue (see above);

Comment: So you're suggesting using jQuery to remove the iFrame and add a new one, the same one I have on my /FAQ page?

Comment: latest update finds the IFrame's mom and gets rid of it - works through the browser :) - yours is a slightly darker colour than the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#askbox').attr("src", "http://jamescharless.com/askbox");
       $('#askbox').removeAttr("id");
   });
```

Comment: I could understand why this should work, but it's not working. http://jamescharless.com/ask Take a look, you'd be able to tell if it was working because the bar that says "Ask anonymously or login" should be darker than the ask button.