# Set iFrame src value dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

**HTML**

```
    <a onclick="readMore('<%:p.Link %>')" class="actionButton">READ MORE</a>

  <iframe id="iFrameBlog"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
  var readMore = function (blogUrl) {
        $('#iFrameBlog').src = blogUrl;
    };
```

**My Question :** When above hyper link clicks,I need to show that url on iFrame's src and need to show that page.But iFrame always stays as empty.Any help ?

[image]

Comment: `$('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com')`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery change the SRC and ID of an iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627767/jquery-change-the-src-and-id-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $('#iFrameBlog').attr('src', blogUrl);
```

instead of

```
 $('#iFrameBlog').src = blogUrl;
```

Comment: Perfect.It's working.But can you tell me why my one doesn't work ?

Comment: if you are using javascript , you can write as `document.getElementById('iFrameBlog').src=blogUrl;`, But in jquery you need to use `.attr()`

Comment: @Sampath, because you're using jQuery, not Vanilla JavaScript. The documentation is easy to read. -> ***http://api.jquery.com/*** So easy, anyone can do it. Even people completely new to jQuery.